# Cannot find the pop up list relating to the #pragma mark compiler directive

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am going through some sample code and notice the compiler directive : "#pragma mark xxx".
Read that the pragma is related to some popup menu in the IDE.  But I don't seem to be able to activate the popup menu.  Can anyone show me how to display the menu relating to "#pragma mark" ?

(Xcode 3.2.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's directly above the code in your source code editor.
[image: Location of popup]

And once you click there you will see this:
[image: the expanded popup]

Comment: Great! I have had quite a frustrating time trying to locate this.  Your illustration is excellent!